# DataGrid extra space in last column

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Trying to remove the extra space in last column, 
i tried various approaches nothing works,
Whenever scroll bar appears, grid behave in strange way
notice the last column width is 70 but somehow grid is adding some extra space.

[image: Last column has extra space even after makeing it not resizable]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
            import mx.collections.IViewCursor;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
            import mx.managers.CursorManager;

            [Bindable]
            private var itemAC:Array = [
                {name:"ABC", quantity:5, color:"Red", size:54, hasLogo:true},
                {name:"ABC1", quantity:6, color:"Green", size:46, hasLogo:false}
                ];

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas width="25%" height="45%"  backgroundColor="red" horizontalCenter="0"
               verticalCenter="0" id="stuff" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        <mx:DataGrid height="100%" width="100%" id="dg" dataProvider="{itemAC}"
                     horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="quantity"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="color"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="size"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="hasLogo" resizable="false"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Canvas>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: try to remove the width property from the fist datagridcolumn. maybe your datagrid control is bigger then 5Columns x 70px.

Comment: Tried to remove width from first column, first column width became more specious, for last column same problem exists.

Comment: Remove resizable="false" from last column and make mx:Canvas width="26%" insted of mx:Canvas width="25%". As width of DataGrid is bigger than canvas width by some px..

Comment: @Mahesh here i am tring to demonstrate the problem when scrollbar coming to grid. this issue arrise only if we have more column in grid to fit on UI, scrollbar appears and then the last column append some extra space.

Comment: which flex sdk are you using ?

Comment: try the horizontalScrollPolicy="on"

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying the width of the datagrid as 100%. So it will occupy whole space available no matter what is the width of each column. Since you are making use of less space than the allocated one the remaining is simply appended at the end. So try to adjust the width as per your requirement

Here is the MXML which makes the Canvas being scrollable horizontally. and removing the width property of Datagrid

```
<mx:Canvas width="352" height="45%"  backgroundColor="red" horizontalCenter="0"
               verticalCenter="0" id="stuff" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
        <mx:DataGrid height="100%" id="dg" dataProvider="{itemAC}"
                     horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="quantity"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="color"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="size"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="hasLogo" resizable="false"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: I have done this using Flex SDK 4.5.1 and making the project as Flex3 compatible one. Hope that helps

Comment: making the parent bigger doesn't solve my issue. issue is when parent is smaller and chield grid is bigger so that scroll bar appears. then the last column width is always bigger then others.

Comment: For the code given above if you make the Canvas width as 25%, then the width of all the columns remains equal but you will get a Scroll bar which is unavoidable given the width of each column

Answer (score 1):

Set datagrid width=350. If you do not want the horizontal scroll bar, set it to 360

Comment: need scrollbar, that's why i demonstrated with parent size lesser.

Comment: this issue occurs only if horizontal scroll bar appears. otherwise grid tries to auto adjust column widths.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give width to all of that leave the first one and you code will be similar like that.

```
<mx:Canvas width="25%" height="45%"  backgroundColor="red" horizontalCenter="0"
           verticalCenter="0" id="stuff" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <mx:DataGrid height="100%" width="100%" id="dg" dataProvider="{itemAC}"
                 horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" resizableColumns="false">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="70" dataField="name"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="quantity"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="color"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="70"  dataField="size"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="hasLogo"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Problem is in **resizable="false"** that is replaced by the **resizableColumns="false"** in DataGrid.

this will definitely solve your problem.

Have @ Nice DAy.....

Comment: here i am trying to demo the width issue if horizontal scroll appears. the last column is always wider then others

Answer (score 1):

I know it is coming a bit too late. But, better late than never.

I had the exact same problem and my solution is to add an empty dumb column on the right hand. It will take up the empty space, and give user a little wiggle room to resize the right most column.

```
//add an empty column at the right side
col = new AdvancedDataGridColumn("");
col.width = 80;
col.sortable = false;
col.draggable = false;
col.editable = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this horizontalScrollPolicy="off"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here.

Solution :

Extra Space is indeed because you have specified datagrid width = 100%

This was helpful with resizing the application to multiple resolutions.

```
<mx:Canvas id="datagridCanvas" width="25%" height="45%"  backgroundColor="red" horizontalCenter="0"
       verticalCenter="0" id="stuff" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
<mx:DataGrid height="100%" width="100%" id="dg" dataProvider="{itemAC}"
             horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" resizableColumns="false">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="70" width="{datagridCanvas.width  * 0.2}" dataField="name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="70" width="{datagridCanvas.width  * 0.2}" dataField="quantity"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="70" width="{datagridCanvas.width  * 0.2}" dataField="color"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="70" width="{datagridCanvas.width  * 0.2}" dataField="size"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn minWidth="70" width="{datagridCanvas.width  * 0.2}" dataField="hasLogo"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```